# Box2d Body can not destroy when touch with another body

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using box2d based game and it detect my player body collied with enemy body but when i write destroybody method for enemy at collied point that time my enemy can not destroy and gives error and my apps crashed.
I show you my code

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
        pos != contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;
        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) 
        {
            CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
            CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
            if (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) 
            {
                // SpriteA = PlayerSprite
                // SpriteB = EnemySprite
                NSString *t=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Over"];
                label.string=t;
                [self removeChild:spriteB cleanup:YES];
                 world->DestroyBody(bodyB);
            } 
            else if (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) 
            {
                //toDestroy.push_back(bodyB);
                NSLog(@"Enemy Touch");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here my spriteB can not destroy.
One more thing is enemy sprite is into the Enemy.mm file.

Please help me i am stuck with this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure both bodies user data is always of type CCSprite ? Maybe your object colliding with a wall or something which has user data other than a sprite

Comment: Yes in my game situation i have both CCSprite which is dynamic body and edge which has static body. But here my player sprite collied with enemy body that time emery body destroy. But not done.So any idea??

Comment: Maybe you have the same enemy body in more than one contact ? (Do you make sure that _contacts contains only unique objects ?

Answer (score 0):

Your making a fundamental  error of handling enemy contact with player different from player contact with enemy(its just the order of thing), you should treat both case the same because you cant know what order they arrive.
Also you arent using toDestroy properly.

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
    std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for(pos = contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
        pos != contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;
        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) 
        {
            CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
            CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();
            if ((spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) ||(spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1)) 
            {
                // SpriteA = PlayerSprite
                // SpriteB = EnemySprite
                NSString *t=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Over"];
                label.string=t;
                [self removeChild:spriteB cleanup:YES];
                 toDestroy.push_back(bodyB);
            } 

        }
        }
//iterate and delete everything from toDestroy
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.After Applying toDestroy and delete every thing from destroy when player body touch to edge body than error occur like EXE_BAD_ACCESS and game crash. What to do for next time collision??

Comment: I think toDestroy might not be initialized check that.